# Angular canActivate Guard with API

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular Webpage, using an python API in the backend. I wanted to add an canActivate Guard, to ensure that the User is in an Adminlist, laying on another Server.

My Problem is, that it seems that the guard doesn't wait for the response of the API, i tested it with a window.alert in the guard itself, and it showed me an "undefined" as Output. When I test my method in my auth.service, I get the correct response in my console.log, so my method seems to return the correct boolean, but my guard seems to not wait for the answer from the API.

I got the following Code:

auth.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { IAuth } from './IAuth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

Acc: boolean;
getauth(): Observable<IAuth['Access']> {
return this.http.get<IAuth['Access']>('http://x.x.x.x:5555/auth');
}

get Access(): boolean {
   this.getauth().subscribe( data =>
   this.Acc = data);
return this.Acc;
}

}
```

And this is my auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor (
      private auth: AuthService,
      private router: Router
  ) {}
    canActivate(
       next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
       state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
          if (!this.auth.Access) {
             this.router.navigate(['/noaccess']);
             window.alert(this.auth.Access);
             window.alert(this.auth.Acc);
           }
          return true;
  }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me solving this problem, like I said, I get the wrong response in the guard (undefined) for both, accessing the property and accessing the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get Access(): boolean {
   this.getauth().subscribe( data => this.Acc = data);
   return this.Acc;
}
```

you don't wait for your HTTP call to finish, so your guard doesn't waith either. Use this instead.

```
get Access(): Observable<any> {
   return this.getauth().pipe(tap(data => this.Acc = data));
}
```

You guard then becomes

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.Access.pipe(map(res => {
      if (!res) { this.router.navigate(['/noaccess']); }
      return !!res;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer man, you really helped me there, one quick question: I'm not totally sure how to redirect the user now to another route ('/noaccess' for example) if the answer from the API is false. 
Sorry for the stupid question, but im pretty new to angular and typescript and dont know how to do some things properly.

Comment: Im wondering the basic nature of canActivate in angular. for example, setting timeout in canActivate doesn't really do anything...it won't wait or do the task in the timeout which for me was just console.log();

Comment: The timeout isn't made for asynchronous coding. And if it doesn't work as expected, feel free to create a [mcve] in a new question